# Gridcontrol becomes blank

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, datagridcomboboxcolumn, gridcontrol

I am using open source code "GridCellCombo.cpp" for grid control. I am stuck with issue. When we click on the combobox sporadically combo box becomes blank. It will not display any items. When I debugged I found that in EndEdit closing the window is causing the issue.

if (::IsWindow(m_hWnd))
    PostMessage(WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);   //commenting out this will work. But this has side effects.

any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue. Due to logical error in my code the window was getting closed twice because of which the combobox was becoming blank.

Thank you.